# Python 3.x email module exhibitng strange behavior?

Tags: email, python-3.x

**The story so far**

I have been working on a project which reads emails and uses information from those emails to construct CLI commands. For the most part everything works great.

The program will connect to the Gmail account using credentials specified in a config file using IMAP. It then locates the oldest unread message and reads it. At this point the email package is used to put the message convert the body text into a string to be parsed through.

**The Issue**

Throughout building and testing this program has worked pretty well. The issue arose however when I tried to package the whole thing into a .exe file. When I tried to run the .exe the program asked me for a Gmail username and password.

I went back and saved the program under a new .py filename to do some troubleshooting. Again when I ran the program it asked for the login credentials. So this behavior arises when the name of the file changes.

Through further testing I found that I was asked for the login credentials whenever the email package was imported. I tried moving the import to later points in the program, including after imaplib had made the connection to the inbox with the supplied credentials, to no avail. As soon as the package was imported everything stopped while it waited for credentials.

**Where I am right now**

I have searched through stack overflow, the python docs, and more Google results than I care to admit. I cannot seem to nail down this issue.

**The Question(s)**

Has anyone else ever seen this? Am I missing something simple an obvious? Is there and easier or better way to go about converting the raw body of the email into a human readable string?

Comment: How are you turning the program into an EXE? Are you making sure that your config file (which stores the gmail credentials you're using) is being packaged up appropriately?

Comment: Sorry should have clarified. I used cxfreeze to bundle it into an exe. And as far as the config file, that is also being read properly. The issue is was discovered when I turned the file into an exe, however if I just save the original .py under another .py file name it still asks for the login credentials whenever the email module is imported.

Comment: You need to show the code for reading credentials. Indeed, the more code the better.